# Correspondance between FileInputStream and SQL Types

Tags: sql, spring, jakarta-ee, stored-procedures, blob

I have to send a file as BLOB to a Stored Procedure. I found a way to do it but I need to use another way (isn't an application of mine).

If I load the file as FileInputStream then I can send it to the stored procedure with the method setBinaryStream of PreparedStatement.

```
File b = new File(pathToFile);
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(b);
ps.setBinaryStream(1, fis, (int)b.length());
```

In this way all works properly.

Unfortunatelly I need to set the file in a map, an istance of the Spring class org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.MapSqlParameterSource.

This is a map  where the key is an integer corresponding to an SQL data type and is taken from the class oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes (or java.sql.Types), the value is the file I have to send.
I've alredy tryed to send a BLOB and set as data type OracleTypes.BLOB but I faced an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.
I also tryed to send the FileInputStream using the data type OracleTypes.LONGVARBINARY and LONGVARCHAR but I received a ClassCastException.

Comment: There's an awful lot of code here for people to read through. Are you able to help by reducing it a little? I'd recommend creating a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which might even direct you to the cause of the problem yourself. At least can you identify which line in your code the stack trace is referring to, as that seems to be the cause of the problem.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but I feel compelled to add that sending an email from a stored procedure seems pretty odd, when you have Spring which will make it all much easier, but perhaps that's out of scope for whatever you're doing.

Comment: I edited the question removing all extra code. I don't know where exactly the exception is raised because this happens in Spring classes.
Unfortunately I have to use a stored procedure: this isn't an application of mine.

Comment: I edited the question because now I know for sure where the problem resides.